# Multi row SQL query into single cell

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I have an issue where I need my multi row SQL query(one column only) to put the results into one cell.
Is there a way to do this?

This is the code I am using, the reason I need it into one cell is because after this part I have another part of code that writes all the cells in one column into separate XML files.

I am trying to either get my multi row query into one single cell or if it is possible to get it as a variable I can just embed into my XML creating code.

All help is much appreciated, let me know if there is more information needed

```
Dim adoDbConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoDbRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim selectCmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim connstring As String

    Dim UID As String
    Dim PWD As String
    Dim Server As String
' Open connection to the SQL Server database
    UID = Worksheets(4).Cells(2, 2).Value       'Username
    PWD = Worksheets(4).Cells(3, 2).Value       'Password
    Server = Worksheets(4).Cells(4, 2).Value    'Database
    connstring = "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=" & Server & ";" & "USER ID=" & UID & ";PASSWORD=" & PWD 'Note, I am using MSDAORA as I use an ORACLE DB, you will need to change it for what DB you are using

    adoDbConn.Open connstring
    'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
    adoDbConn.CommandTimeout = 900
    ' Execute the select query
   selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDbConn
   selectCmd.CommandText = Worksheets(1).Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13).Value
Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)
' Activate the Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
   ws.Activate
' Put the query results starting from cell N2
If adoDbRs.EOF = False Then ws.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).CopyFromRecordset adoDbRs
' Close the connection and free the memory
   adoDbRs.Close
Set adoDbRs = Nothing
Set selectCmd = Nothing
   adoDbConn.Close
Set adoDbConn = Nothing
```

Comment: I suppose you could loop thru the records and insert a line break between each value and then set the result to the cell, but depending on the size of the recordset, you may run into length problems for the cell. Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: My original solution had the sql create a 1 row output that worked fine, until some of the query results made the string too big. This makes me need to look at alternatives. The best solution would be if i could use the CONCAT function in some way on the results and then just create my XML file from that.

Comment: `myValue = adoDbRs.GetString()` then put that in the cell or use it in your XML
 https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_getstring.asp

Comment: @TimWilliams do you know if there is a limit to that? because I seem to be missing some part. It does what I want tho, just doesnt take all the data

Comment: How much data do you have?  There will be a limit to what you can put in a cell.

Comment: yeah I think that was the case, but I worked around it and it works great now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using Tim Williams suggestion `myValue = adoDbRs.GetString()` from the comments and embedding my XML file creation to use that value instead of cell value.

```
Dim adoDbRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim selectCmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim connstring As String

Dim UID As String
Dim PWD As String
Dim Server As String
' Open connection to the SQL Server database
    UID = Worksheets(4).Cells(2, 2).Value       'Användarnamn
    PWD = Worksheets(4).Cells(3, 2).Value       'Lösenord
    Server = Worksheets(4).Cells(4, 2).Value    'Databas
    connstring = "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=" & Server & ";" & "USER ID=" & UID & ";PASSWORD=" & PWD 'Note, I am using MSDAORA as I use an ORACLE DB, you will need to change it for what DB you are using

    adoDbConn.Open connstring
    'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
    adoDbConn.CommandTimeout = 900
    ' Execute the select query
   selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDbConn
   selectCmd.CommandText = Worksheets(1).Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13).Value
Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)

' Activate the Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
   ws.Activate

' Put the query results into string
Dim QueryResult As String
    QueryResult = adoDbRs.GetString()

' Close the connection and free the memory
   adoDbRs.Close
Set adoDbRs = Nothing
Set selectCmd = Nothing
   adoDbConn.Close
Set adoDbConn = Nothing

' Create XML file
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim c As Range

    strName = Worksheets(1).Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 15).Value
    strPath = Worksheets(4).Cells(7, 2).Value

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strPath & strName)
    oFile.Write QueryResult
    oFile.Close
```